# Domino Tiling Game

Tags: strategy, game-theory, pencil-and-paper-games, dominoes

Two players are presented an $n\times n$ grid. They take turns placing a piece on the board until no more moves are possible. The last player able to make a move is the winner. The pieces are $2\times 1$ dominoes and $3\times 1$ trominoes. Both players have an infinite supply of both pieces. When placing a piece, it cannot lie on top of previously placed pieces. (Instead of placing pieces on a board, you may instead imagine two players circling appropriately sized regions on grid paper)

For all $n\ge 1$, determine which player wins, and describe the strategy to guarantee a win.

Comment: Surely this is a [tag:strategy] puzzle... and would that make it inelegible for the FTC?

Comment: @boboquack Unfortunately, I think you're right. I was not thinking about the strategy tag when I made this, but now I see that it is probably the best-fitting tag. I will remove this entry from FTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n = 1$, it's trivial that first player can't win since he can't make any move.

Also for $n = 2$, both players can make the moves so the board will be full (by placing two $1 \times 2$ tiles), hence the first player can't win too.

But for $n \geq 3$,

> First player will win if $n$ is odd and second player will win if $n$ is even.
>
>  The strategy is simply to mirror (to the center point of the grid) the opponent's moves. For first player if $n$ is odd, he can simply put $1 \times 3$ tile in the middle at the beginning.

For more details:

> By mirroring to the center point of the grid means the cell on up left is "pairing" to the cell on down right. The cell on $i$-th row from above and $j$-th column from left is pairing to the cell on $i$-th row from **below** and $j$-th column from **right**.
>
>  Take a note that the $1 \times 2$ and $1 \times 3$ tiles **will not** occupy two cells which are pairing to each other (except the first $1 \times 3$ one from first player when $n$ is odd). *Small proof: The pairing is on the different row and column.*
>
>  Initially, every two cells which are pairing to each other are **both** unoccupied or occupied.
>  By previous statement, if one put the unoccupied cells; the other one may simply put their pairs since they must be unoccupied too. By doing so, the integrity is still same: every two cells which are pairing to each other are **both** unoccupied or occupied.
>
>  Therefore, the player who copied the opponents moves will win the game.

Comment: Do you think you could explain the strategy in greater detail? And more about why/how it works.

Comment: @Riley ok I'm trying. I'm sorry I can't use any images here because imgur is currently blocked in my country lol.